# Laravel 5.5 event will not fire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a larval project that has two events when an user is registered. One event will create all the roles and permissions for the user and the other event will send a welcome email to the user. In the event service provider I have this:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\NewUser' => [
        'App\Listeners\CreateAuthorization',
        'App\Listeners\SendWelcomeEmail',
    ],
];
```

In the new user event, I have the user being passed in the constructor like below:

```
class NewUser
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
}
}
```

I have tried implementing only one listener so far and that is the `CreateAuthorization` listener

```
class CreateAuthorization
{
public function __construct()
{
    //
}
public function handle(NewUser $event)
{
    //
    Log::info('This is some useful information.');
    $user_role = new UserRole();
    $user_role->user_id = $event->user->id;
    $user_role->permission_id = $role->id;
    $user_role->save();
}
}
```

In the model class of the user I have this to link the events together.

```
protected $events = [
    'created' => NewUser::class
];
```

I have tried clearing my cache and logging messages, but from what I see in the log, messages are not even showing up which leads me to think that the event is not even being fired when an user is created. I am super lost on how to solve this issue.

Comment: The [L5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) show an Eloquent model's event property as `$dispatchesEvents` rather than `$events`. Maybe that's your issue?

Comment: Do you have [Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts) configured?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the laravel documentation and I also tested.

```
// Wrong
protected $events = [
    'created' => NewUser::class
];
```

The correct one should be

```
// Correct
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => NewUser::class
];
```

You can read more about this on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events